# Create user for alternate port

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I am running a private MySQL instance on WebFaction

WebFaction is a shared host who provides both for their public MySQL instance and for your own private MySQL instance. The private instance is a 1-click install using their system which then provides a root user and port to you. The public instance is always just localhost, and the private instance is localhost:port.

What is the proper way to set up a user for that private instance?

`CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost:port' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
`CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
`CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Does it matter?

I'm running into an issue trying to set up a Simplified Machines forum instance. The SMF forum will connect to localhost just fine, and it seems to connect to localhost:port okay (at the point in code where it makes the connection to the DB, it is successful), but then will only read and write to localhost and not localhost:port.

I have successfully created a db user which can connect to, read, and write via localhost:port, but refuses to do so via SMF.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please post the error via SMF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

`CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';`
`CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';`

`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';`
`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';`

In the php.ini:
`mysql.default_port = <private instance port>`

In the forum settings, set database host to:
`127.0.0.1`